# What's the best way to define dependencies between multiple ant build files?

Tags: ant, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a bunch of modules which I'd like to all have their own ant build files.  However, modules have dependencies on other modules.  What's the best way to define dependencies between build files?

I've looked at the <import>, <ant>, and <antcall> tasks, but it seems like maybe there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/index.html) ([features](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/features.html)) for managing your dependencies. There's a tutorial on [how to use Ivy in a multiple project environment](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-release/tutorial/multiproject.html) which sounds like what you're after. I'd recommend following through [the tutorials from the beginning](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-release/tutorial.html) as it can be a bit tricky to get your head around it to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I try to put all the definitions into [Antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html) and including them into the main `build.xml` file.  If you write your macros following the "convention over configuration" rule, you'll be surprised to see how concise Ant can be.

If you want to see an example, you can take a look at [my sandbox](http://code.google.com/p/workingonit/source/browse/trunk/depictus/build.xml) on Google code

Comment: We have done this for our builds, with the common Ant stuff in one file and every file including that one. It removes the problem of duplicating XML all over the place quite nicely, but then there is the other problem of running the same step multiple times in the one build...